# Where ist the infinity loop?

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop

somebody care to tell me where the problem with this function is?

Something is wrong with this complex:

```
buildBoard :: String -> Board
buildBoard xs = buildBoard' ("+" ++ xs ++ "+") []

buildBoard' :: String -> [Cell] -> Board
buildBoard' [] _ = [[]] 
buildBoard' xs result
|head xs == ',' && xs!!1 == ',' = buildBoard' (tail xs) (Empty:result)
|head xs == 'w' =
    buildBoard' (drop (getFirstNonNumber 0) xs) (Piece White intConversion : result)
|head xs == 'b' =
    buildBoard' (drop (getFirstNonNumber 0) xs) (Piece White intConversion : result)
|head xs == '/' && xs!!1 == ',' = buildBoard' (tail xs) (Empty:result)
|head xs == ',' && xs!!1 == '/' = buildBoard' (tail xs) (Empty:result)
|head xs == '+' && xs!!1 == ',' = buildBoard' (tail xs) (Empty:result)
|head xs == '+' && xs!!1 `elem` ['b','w'] = buildBoard' (tail xs) result
|head xs == ',' && xs!!1 == '+' = buildBoard2 (reverse (Empty:result))
|head xs == '+' = buildBoard2 (reverse result)
|otherwise = buildBoard2 (reverse result)
 where intConversion = read [xs!!1..xs!!(getFirstNonNumber 0 -1)] :: Int
     getFirstNonNumber num = if xs!!num `elem` [',','/']  then num else getFirstNonNumber num+1

separate :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
separate _ [] = []
separate n l
| n > 0 = take n l : separate n (drop n l)
| otherwise = []

buildBoard2 :: [Cell] -> Board
buildBoard2 = separate 9
```

---

some additional info about what Cell, Board etc is:

```
data Player = Black | White deriving Show
data Cell = Piece Player Int | Empty deriving Show
data Pos = Pos { col :: Char, row :: Int } deriving Show
type Board = [[Cell]]
```

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem? (as in: what is it supposed to do, and what does it do instead?)

Comment: Good question, running a HSpec test I get a timeout concerning this particular block of code.

Comment: Its supposed to convert a String like this into a Board
 
 ,w84,w41,w56,w170,w56,w41,w84,/,,w24,w40,w17,w40,w48,,/,,,w16,w16,w16,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,b1,b1,b1,,,/,,b3,b130,b17,b130,b129,,/,b69,b146,b131,b170,b131,b146,b69,

Answer (score 5):

Here, at least, is one:

```
getFirstNonNumber num = if ... then num else getFirstNonNumber num+1
```

You almost certainly meant that last call to be:

```
getFirstNonNumber (num+1)
```